# jquery toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a function I want a div to increase height and opacity and when click again it should return to it's original state so I used toggle function to do that now the problem is that when page loads the button get disappears

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cm_now').toggle(function() {
    $('.search_bx_ar').css({
      'opacity': '1'
    });
    $('.search_bx_ar').css({
      'height': '40px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.search_bx_ar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
}

.compare_sr_btn {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
}

.compare_sr_btn>#cm_now {
  background-color: #2b7f7f;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare_sr_btn">
  <input type="button" id="cm_now" value="Compare Now" />
</div>
<div class="search_bx_ar">
  <input class="form-control top_search" id="data_mid" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocompl();" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle link please...

Comment: @Mr_Panda He did.

Comment: please check m updated question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Toggle is used to hide or show an element. Since you run the function as soon as the page is loaded, the button is immediately hidden with a nice little animation.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

See if this does what you want:

```js
var buttonState = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cm_now').click(function() {
        if(buttonState == 0) {
            $('.search_bx_ar').css({'opacity': '1'});
            $('.search_bx_ar').css({'height' : '40px'});
     } else {
            $('.search_bx_ar').css({'opacity': '0.5'});
            $('.search_bx_ar').css({'height' : '20px'});
        }
        buttonState = 1 - buttonState; //a clever way to toggle between 0 and 1
    });
});
```

```css
.search_bx_ar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0px;
 transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
 -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
 -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
}
.compare_sr_btn {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
}

.compare_sr_btn > #cm_now {
    background-color: #2b7f7f;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare_sr_btn">
    <button id="cm_now">Compare Now</button>
</div>
<div class="search_bx_ar">
    <input class="form-control top_search" id="data_mid" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocompl();" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Comment: so what should I do what shoudl be the solution ?

Comment: @UsmanKhan I've edited my answer, see if that helps you. I _think_ I worked out what you want to happen, but if not let me know and I'll see if I can do more to help :)

Comment: but when I click again it does not come to it's original state

Comment: this is the closest solution by far.. you might have to remove or adjust the height in the original css and just set it using jquery for it to work correctly (seeing as important doesn't work in jquery)

Comment: what is the 'original state' - no compare button?  you can add this in

Comment: @UsmanKhan The "original state" was invisible, so just change this line `$('.search_bx_ar').css({'opacity': '0.5'});` to be this `$('.search_bx_ar').css({'opacity': '0'});`, but if you couldn't figure that out on your own, I think you need to do some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have not added any click handler to `[toggle.][2]`

You are just calling the toggle on document ready which will be called immediately after dom loaded.

> The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected
>   elements.
>
> This method checks the selected elements for visibility. show() is run
>   if an element is hidden. hide() is run if an element is visible - This
>   creates a toggle effect.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cm_now').click(function() {

    $('#cm_now').toggle(function() {
      $('.search_bx_ar').css({
        'opacity': '1'
      });
      $('.search_bx_ar').css({
        'height': '40px'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.search_bx_ar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
}

.compare_sr_btn {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
}

.compare_sr_btn>#cm_now {
  background-color: #2b7f7f;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare_sr_btn">
  <input type="button" id="cm_now" value="Compare Now" />
</div>
<div class="search_bx_ar">
  <input class="form-control top_search" id="data_mid" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocompl();" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".cm_now").click(function() {
  $('.cm_now').toggleClass("seach-animate");
  });
```

```css
.search_bx_ar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
}

.compare_sr_btn {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
}

.cm_now {
  background-color: #2b7f7f;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.seach-animate {
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="compare_sr_btn">
          <input type="button" class="cm_now" value="Compare Now" />
        </div>
        <div class="search_bx_ar">
          <input class="form-control top_search" id="data_mid" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocompl();" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can toggle your button when it clicked .Other wise toggle and disappear after document ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#cm_now").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggle(function() {
    $('.search_bx_ar').css({
      'opacity': '1'
    });
    $('.search_bx_ar').css({
      'height': '40px'
    });
  });
  });
});
```

```css
.search_bx_ar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
}

.compare_sr_btn {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
}

.compare_sr_btn>#cm_now {
  background-color: #2b7f7f;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare_sr_btn">
  <input type="button" id="cm_now" value="Compare Now" />
</div>
<div class="search_bx_ar">
  <input class="form-control top_search" id="data_mid" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocompl();" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt that's what he wanted to do.